# Symfony 3.0.1 EventDispatcher

Tags: php, symfony

I'm writing a RequestListener and I look like to get the EventDispatcher.
It was working on previous version of Symfony.
I checked the CHANGELOG.md :

> The method getListenerPriority($eventName, $listener) has been added
>   to the EventDispatcherInterface. The methods Event::setDispatcher(),
>   Event::getDispatcher(), Event::setName() and Event::getName() have
>   been removed. The event dispatcher and the event name are passed to
>   the listener call.

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
  $dispatcher = $event->getDispatcher();
}
```

How can I get the event dispatcher ?

Thanks

Comment: Read: `The event dispatcher and the event name are passed to the listener call.`

Comment: Have you an example to use this ?

Comment: The answer bellow (by @Cerad) is 100% correct.  Take a look. ;)

Comment: I've just tried and it's work, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html#eventdispatcher-aware-events-and-listeners

```
public function onKernelRequest(
  GetResponseEvent $event, 
  $eventName, 
  EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher) 
{

}
```